# Remove double http:// from input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates

I have a textarea with a default value of `http://`. Now when an user pastes in an url (if they don't know what they are doing, like most people) it comes out like this `http://http://www.google.com`. I've seen a site that as soon as you have `http://http://` it removes one via JavaScript.

I am not familiar with JavaScript, so can anyone help me?

I don't want to clear the field on focus only.

Comment: Ajax is an entirely different story. It's "just" JavaScript. I've rephrased your question accordingly.

Comment: I edited my answer to include more info about when to call the function

Comment: I added an answer that catches ctrl+v pastes

Comment: Just want to add my appreciation that you are actually doing this at all... a lot of sites don't care about inconveniencing the user with issues like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need ajax to do that just simple javascript can do the trick.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#idofurtextfield').blur(function(){

        jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/(http:\/\/)\1/, '$1'));

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Keeping it simple and using the [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function:

```
var url = "http://http://google.com";
url = url.replace("http://http://","http://");
```

... this will basically replace the first string `"http://http://"` by the second, "`http://"`.

You'll need to call this when the content of the field change. For instance using jQuery:

```
$("#myfield").change(function(e){
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace("http://http://","http://"));
});
```

without jQuery (not 100% sure about this):

```
document.getElementById("myfield").onChange = function(){
  var val=document.getElementById("myfield").value;
  document.getElementById("myfield").value = value.replace("http://http://","http://");
}
```

---

Unrelated but worth mentioning: This is not AJAX, it is simple javascript. Ajax is the term used when you try to have asynchronous communication with a server using the XMLHTTP object

> Ajax (shorthand for asynchronous
>   JavaScript and XML) is a group of
>   interrelated web development
>   techniques used on the client-side to
>   create interactive web applications.
>   With Ajax, web applications can
>   retrieve data from the server
>   asynchronously in the background
>   without interfering with the display
>   and behavior of the existing page.

([via](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)))

Comment: The question here is, when to call that?

Comment: @jandy: I didn't quite got it from the question, but here's an edit

Answer (score 2):

No Ajax at all to do that kind of magic.

This will do it:

```
$(function(){
  $('textarea').bind('keydown', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
     if(e.which === 86 && e.ctrlKey){
       setTimeout(function(){
          $this.val($this.val().replace(/http:\/\/http:\/\//,"http://"));
       }, 1);
     }
  });
});​
```

This will replace `http://` on `ctrl+v` if already exists.
You might also want to call the same routine on a `change` event if an user uses
a contextmenu to paste.

Comment: aha, pretty cool! would that work in IE? not sure about e.ctrlKey

Comment: e.ctrlKey should be normalized through jQuery, so yes. Should work crossbrowser.

Answer (score 1):

Always nice to have a none regex option (saving those precious micro-seconds!):

```
var url = "http://http://google.com";
url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("http://"));

// -> "http://google.com"
```